# How to send SMS within my iOS app without using MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In my application, I want a user to input a phone number, press start, and then every 30 minutes that inputted phone number will receive a text message.

I know `MFMessageComposeViewController` can open up the text view controller to send a message with a specific body, but I want the message to be sent automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't do it without `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Apple won't allow sending SMS without user interaction.

I've alternate solution of this, out of scope of iOS.

Use web service API. Create a web service at server side that send a message to specific number(s) that accept numbers as parameters with request.

At specific time interval (according to your requirement) send a web service call with number as request parameter.

Web server can do it. It can send message to any device.

Answer (score 0):

The best method be to use a messaging service where you can send the submitted number to a server and handle the number from there. Apple doesn't allow you to natively send any messages without users interaction.